# Putting RSA keys into azure key vault

Tags: ssh, azure, git, ssh-keys, automation

How can I store my key pair (typically the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) in azure key vault.
I want to put the public key in my GIT service and allow a virtual machine to download the private key from Azure key vault -> So that it can access GIT securely.

I tried making a pair of PEM files and combining them into a pfx and uploading that as a secret bu the file I get back appears to be completely different to either pem file.

I also tried manually inputting my secret key into Azure but it turns the newlines into spaces.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use [Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs) to upload `id_rsa` to Azure Key Vault.

```
azure keyvault secret set --name shui --vault-name shui --file ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You could use `-h` to get help.

```
--file <file-name>                 the file that contains the secret value to be uploaded; cannot be used along with the --value or --json-value flag
```

You could also download secret from key vault.

```
az keyvault secret download --name shui --vault-name shui --file ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I compare the keys on my lab. They are same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the OP, I just read this and tested it and filed it away as useful knowledge and felt I owed you a vote up + comment :). Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: >Sorry, I'm not the OP, I just read this and tested it and filed it away as useful knowledge and felt I owed you a vote up + comment :)

Sounds funny. So friendly community.

Comment: I'm OP, thanks a lot Walter! I couldn't get the native CLI to work but did it through Python. Was able to log in, store my key and retrieve it.
The -h tip was really helpful because it shows much more information than when you just get something wrong

Comment: what are the `-u` and `-s` flags? I don't see them on `azure-cli (2.0.14)`

Comment: @sg Hi, you use cli 1.0? -u vault name -s secret name.

Comment: FYI, following is proper ways to get secret `get` does not work anymore. `az keyvault secret download --name <KeyNameHere> --vault-name <vaultNamehere> --file <filename here>`

Comment: The azure command line tool (in Python) is az NOT azure. So the command above needs to have azure replaced with az. The second command's syntax is correct.

Answer (score 21):

The previous answer by Shengbao Shui shows the command to store a secret using the Azure CLI 1.0 (Node). For [Azure CLI 2.0 (Python)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) use the following syntax:

#### Set / Store Key:

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name 'myvault' -n 'secret-name' -f '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

#### Arguments:

```
Arguments
    --name -n    [Required]: Name of the secret.
    --vault-name [Required]: Name of the key vault.
    --description          : Description of the secret contents (e.g. password, connection string,
                             etc).
    --disabled             : Create secret in disabled state.  Allowed values: false, true.
    --expires              : Expiration UTC datetime  (Y-m-d'T'H:M:S'Z').
    --not-before           : Key not usable before the provided UTC datetime  (Y-m-d'T'H:M:S'Z').
    --tags                 : Space-separated tags in 'key[=value]' format. Use '' to clear existing
                             tags.

Content Source Arguments
    --encoding -e          : Source file encoding. The value is saved as a tag (`file-
                             encoding=<val>`) and used during download to automatically encode the
                             resulting file.  Allowed values: ascii, base64, hex, utf-16be,
                             utf-16le, utf-8.  Default: utf-8.
    --file -f              : Source file for secret. Use in conjunction with '--encoding'.
    --value                : Plain text secret value. Cannot be used with '--file' or '--encoding'.

Global Arguments
    --debug                : Increase logging verbosity to show all debug logs.
    --help -h              : Show this help message and exit.
    --output -o            : Output format.  Allowed values: json, jsonc, table, tsv.  Default:
                             json.
    --query                : JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more information
                             and examples.
    --verbose              : Increase logging verbosity. Use --debug for full debug logs.
```

#### Retrieve / Get Key:

Save the key to a file `~/.ssh/mykey` using [the jq utility.](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
az keyvault secret show --vault-name myvault --name 'secret-name' | jq -r .value > ~/.ssh/mykey
```

Files may print with a trailing newline, which you can remove with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' ~/.ssh/mykey

# Set permissions to user-read only
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/mykey
```

Generate the public key from the private key file...

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/myfile > ~/.ssh/myfile.pub
```

Comment: You can combine the built-in jmespath `--query` option of `az` with the `-o tsv` option to output the key without requiring `jq`: `az keyvault secret show --vault-name myvault --name 'secret-name' --query "value" -o tsv > ~/.ssh/mykey`

Answer (score 0):

If we want to store the ssh key in KeyVault in ASCII Encoded format then we can use the below command.
`$az keyvault secret set –-vault-name <KEY_VAULT_NAME> -–name <NAME_OF_THE_KEY> –-file <PATH_OF_THE_SSH_KEY_FILE> -–encoding ascii`